# How to check floating number count of Float numbers using Swift?

Tags: swift, string-formatting

I am working with numbers retrieved as strings from a database.

So numbers are usually like: `1.43`, `21.4`, `3.4`, `321.323`, `765` etc.

I want to format those string into: `1.43%`, `21.40%`, `3.40%`, `321.32%`, `765.00%`

So, I am assuming I have to check whether there is a floating number, if so how many and then apply proper formatting when displaying.

I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use right format:

```
let numbers = [1.43, 21.4, 3.4, 321.323, 765]
let percents = numbers.map({ String(format: "%.2f%%", $0) })
print(percents) // ["1.43%", "21.40%", "3.40%", "321.32%", "765.00%"]
```

---

> but I have to handle them individually one-by-one

Work with single number:

```
let number = 1.43
let percent = String(format: "%.2f%%", number)
print(percent) // "1.43%"
```

Iterate through the array of numbers:

```
let numbers = [1.43, 21.4, 3.4, 321.323, 765]

numbers.forEach { number in
    let percent = String(format: "%.2f%%", number)
    print(percent)
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I have to handle them individually one-by-one? Instead of mass array modification. Could you help me please?

Comment: I am sorry but I see values like 6.8%, 7.0%

Comment: @sc13, for what numbers?

Comment: 6.8 is being displayed as 6.8%, 7.0 is as 7.0%.

Comment: @sc13, i tested these numbers in playground and get 6.80% and 7.00%.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistyping a value. Must be very tired. Thank you so much it works!